# Teamcity configuration for java web pproject

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

Please help me to find good solution for configure teamcity for java-maven project with buildsteps, triggers, build features and  another options. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I did it for myself. I read about maven goals and maven plugins [THERE][1] and understand about build steps in teamcity. =)